# Can't create new tab bar controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

When i try to create a new tab bar controller it comes like this. What can be the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1.Add new UIViewController in storyboard

2.Drag segue from Tab bar Controller to that ViewController

3.And Select Relationship segue ->view Controllers

There you Go..!

Comment: When I drag tab bar controller, it will goes like the picture I shared. However, when I close and re-open my Mac it seems like fixed.

Comment: Which version of xcode are you using?did you try it by creating new project?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.1. Yes I tried to do it on a new project. Even this is a temp and new project.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to add uiviewcontroller to tabor is.

1) Add one uiviewcontroleller on the story board.

2) Select that and click on Editor> Embed In > Tabbar Controller

3) That initialises a new tabor controller with one uiviewcontroller.

If you want to add additional items to your tabar.
Add new uiviewcontroller and CTRL + Click + drag to new uiviewcontroller from the taborcontroller.When you choose the relationship segue, that would add your second view controller.

Comment: I also tried this but the problem is I had this problem with all of tab bar items. Therefore, it doesn't matter if I add it like in editor -> embed in or add tab bar manually and add a new item to it. However, I closed and reopened my Mac and it seems like fixed.